# How do you handle security with a login form on every page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it secure to submit from a HTTP form to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274274/is-it-secure-to-submit-from-a-http-form-to-https)

Is there a safe way to include a username and password form on every page of a website without using HTTPS for every page?

EDIT: I want users to be able to login from any page, there would be a small area for a username and password in the header of the website, however not all pages will be HTTPS.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? Sent in a POST or GET request? And why would you send each time?

Comment: It might be worth considering [using HTTPS for every page](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted.html). (Of course, it might not too.)

Comment: @WouterdeKort, see latest update to question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274274/is-it-secure-to-submit-from-a-http-form-to-https