# How to post a form to django site, securely and from another site

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, security

I have a django app which need to receive post requests from  another site using html+javascript.
For example i have **mydjangosite.com** and  **smallhtmlsite.com**
What i want is : user visit **smallhtmlsite.com** and fill a form, then he pushing submit button and **mydjangosite.com** receive request and create objects(form saving models actually).
So i will have a view which will handle this requests. But how can these been done securely?

Comment: See here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274274/is-it-secure-to-submit-from-a-http-form-to-https. You will have CSRF errors and lack security. Keep in mind that CSRF stands for cross-site request forgery. An API is probably the only way.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a django app which need to receive post requests from another
>   site using html+javascript.

You don't *have to* ! You can build an API instead ;)

You create an API call - **small site** calls the API of **main site**. In that situation, the form is handled by a view in **small site** and the API is called via the server. Check out Django REST Framework.

Note: That solution wouldn't stop you from using AJAX but it would avoid cross domain issues.

Comment: Sorry, but that suggestion does not helped for me. I still need a solution in which i can have different sites (built on html+js only) posting data to my django app securely.

Comment: I need a solution for different sites , so i have mydjangosite.com receiving post requests from different sites, based on different lanuages(php,ruby, etc...) so i decided to have only js and html. am i right?

Comment: Well an API is the only clean way to do it which would always work. I think you can do what you want in HTML5 but it won't work in all browsers.