# Is sending login credentials from an HTTP page secure?

Tags: security, ssl, https

Scenario: the web page I'm on uses HTTP. It includes a form to login. The form action uses HTTPS.

Question: are my login credentials secure, or must the page I'm on use HTTPS also?

Follow-up from: https://twitter.com/falkowski/status/525354785437147136

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it secure to submit from a HTTP form to HTTPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274274/is-it-secure-to-submit-from-a-http-form-to-https)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is only the form action that requires HTTPS.

However, IE in particular complains mightily when you try to mix secure and insecure resources. In addition, having such a configuration indicates that the writers of that service are being lazy.

The design would preclude the latest security configurations such as Strict Transport Security & Perfect Forward Secrecy and will also prevent the site from using SPDY. Bad design.

Even worse from a user perspective is that it is almost impossible to check that the site is using a secure connection and it would be trivial for that form submission to be changed to non-secure without anyone being any the wiser. Bad design!!

I would point out though, that with was common practice a few years ago when HTTPS was a significant overhead on web servers. Things have moved on though and this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 0):

Reference from another thread: [Is it secure to submit from a HTTP form to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274274/is-it-secure-to-submit-from-a-http-form-to-https)

TLDR: the submission itself is technically secure, but because the surrounding page is susceptible to a MITM attack it's not.